# Sonar6 - How to show quality gate passed conditions in project dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

In previous sonarqube versions it was possible to configure the Quality Gate widget in project dashboard pages to "show passed conditions". Where can I configure this in sonarqube 6.2 ?

Comment: To clarify: you want to show not just warning/error conditions, but also the ones the project got right?

Comment: right, all quality gate conditions would be shown, no matter if they passed, failed or were at warning level.